# Do I need Virtual Box on Ubuntu to create docker machine?

Tags: ubuntu, docker, docker-machine

I recently installed docker-ce on Ubunutu 16.04 and configured docker-machine package by following the instructions in the Docker documentations.

While testing the installation, the `docker run` command executed fine however `docker-machine create` command asked for Virtual Box configured.

As per my understanding, docker containers run on Linux and hence need VirtualBox on either Mac or Windows which do not have Hyper-V support but why it is needed on Ubuntu?

What is the use of Virtual Box in creating Docker Machine?

Comment: No, you don't need virtual box to run docker containers. You might want to look [What is docker machine](https://docs.docker.com/machine/overview/#what-is-docker-machine), because it needs virtual host.

Comment: You only need a virtual machine to run docker on a non Linux box.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The idea behind Docker Machine is to allow user to install Docker Engine (i.e. the Docker daemon) on virtual hosts. These hosts can be VMs running on virtualization tools like VirtualBox and KVM on your local machine, or remote VMs running in your company's data center or cloud providers like AWS, DigitalOcean etc. Once the Docker Engine is installed, these hosts can also be managed by Docker Machine, from for example, your local machine.

You don't need Docker Machine to run Docker on Ubuntu. But if you would like to create a swarm cluster of multiple Docker hosts on your machine, then you can utilize Docker Machine and VirtualBox to create multiple VMs, each of which is a Docker host.

You can learn more about Docker Machine [here](https://docs.docker.com/machine/overview/).

Comment: Why the downvote? The question is asking for why is Docker Machine needed on Ubuntu. And what's VirtualBox used for in creating Docker Machine. Not _how_ to create a Docker host using Docker Machine and the Virtual Box driver.

Comment: @Rahul Did this answer your question?

Comment: gave you an upvote and thank you for your explanation. If each VM is a docker host. One question I cant seem to find an answer to is around nested virtualization. What if I want to have multiple docker hosts defined on a single vm (kind of like docker toolbox on windows + virtualbox), in my virtualbox ubuntu instance?

Comment: @qodeninja I don't think you can do that. What's your use case for that?

Comment: at the time I didnt understand the nature of docker-machine vs docker -- I wanted to run docker-machine from within virtualbox to launch other docker hosts within it but it turns out I can only do that on a remote cloud platform and not locally. Took me a minute. I'm not ready to deploy to a cloud environment yet so looks like Im stuck with docker-toolbox for now

Comment: If you want multiple docker hosts locally, can't you run docker-machine from your host OS?

Comment: indeed I can, like I said I hadn't understood the nature of docker-machine. The issue has to do with my workflow. I dont usually dev in Windows, rather on my Ubuntu VM. I wanted to launch docker hosts from my dev environment, seems like I can only do it from Windows which requires me to use docker-toolbox/git-bash.

Comment: This is the answer that I am looking for! Thanks.